# Children's book with a lost treasure in a hidden valley only accessible by swimming underwater

Tags: identification-request, mystery-novels

Okay, this has nagged me for years. I read a children's book circa 1970, set in the western US in early-mid-20th century.  Horses and trucks both.  A mystery. Protagonists two boys and one girl.  There is a lost treasure (a mine?) in a hidden valley somewhere in a small mountain range.  One character takes a job as a helper to a peddler (a handyman?) who drives a van throughout the region.  Eventually the main characters discover that the hidden valley can only be found by swimming underwater (through a pool or stream?).

Probably not a classic, but I'd love to re-read, enjoy and exorcise!

Comment: This doesn't fit enough of the clues to be likely, unfortunately, but a couple things about this are reminding me of Over Sea Under Stone by Susan Cooper! Unlikely though unless some details are misremembered.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the [Three Investigators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Investigators) series. And you may be conflating two or more books.  [list of books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_American_series_of_The_Three_Investigators)

The books had various geographical settings. THe detectives did a lot of traveling. There was definitely at least one with a Western setting. It's a long time since I read them. Memory is hazy. I think the Western setting is probably *The Mystery of Death Trap Mine*.  There was a different book where they discovered a cave that could only be reached by swimming through an underwater tunnel. I think that was probably *The Secret of Skeleton Island*.

Comment: OP would be misremembering a _lot_ if it's this. "Protagonists two boys and one girl", and the lost treasure in a mine sounds like *Green Ghost* which is very different from *Skeleton Island* in the Three Investigators series.